# StickyGridHeaders width of the header line

Tags: android

As you can see from the following picture:

[image: Where the C letter is is not wrapping the whole width]

When I scroll to the letter the green line on the header fills the space (as B letter) but when not fills only the letter (as C letter).

I want the C letter to also fill the whole space.

Here is the code I used taken Tonic Artos' Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/itemGridHeader"
                 android:layout_width="0dip"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:gravity="left"
                 android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                 android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                 android:paddingTop="4dp"
                 android:textColor="@color/myColor"
                 android:textSize="16.5sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:textAllCaps="true"
                 >
         </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:background="@color/myColor" >
 </FrameLayout>
```

And here is the link of the code:
https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/blob/master/Example/res/layout/header.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this question is a bit old, but I was struggling with the same problem today and I wanted to share what I did.

[image: Screenshot with the same problem]

What it was happening is that I was using gradle to add the dependency to this library and I knew that without gradle in a previous version it was working at some point, so I deleted the dependency and added this jar that I had among my files and then it was fixed.

[stickygridheaders.jar file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Vv-MW2PsnxSnZtRWhlRUFKUFk/view?usp=sharing)