# StickyGridHeader custom header display wrong size

Tags: android, android-gridview

I use [StickyGridHeader](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) library with a custom header view like image below. The problem is this header only work when it's sticky on the top. On normal state, it show width size incorrectly, I think it caused by measuring header size from [StickyGridHeadersGridView](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/blob/master/Library/src/com/tonicartos/widget/stickygridheaders/StickyGridHeadersGridView.java#L633)

[image]

Here is my header layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHeaderName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvHeaderDate"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="aaa"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHeaderDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="aaa"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

  <!--gray line-->
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvHeaderDate"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/gray_line" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And my adapter:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapter {

     // initialize image item ...


    @Override
    public int getCountForHeader(int position) {
        return getHeaderItem(position).getImages().size();
    }

    public GalleryItem getHeaderItem(int position) {
        return parents.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        HeaderViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_header_gallery, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvHeaderName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderName);
            viewHolder.tvHeaderDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderDate);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tvHeaderName.setText(getHeaderItem(position).getGroupName());
        viewHolder.tvHeaderDate.setText(getHeaderItem(position).getTime());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumHeaders() {
        return parents.size();
    }

    private static class HeaderViewHolder {
        public TextView tvHeaderName;
        public TextView tvHeaderDate;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try what I say in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26414478/1557367).
Basically, you have to replace your stickygridheaders.jar or your dependency in gradle with this other jar [stickygridheaders.jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Vv-MW2PsnxSnZtRWhlRUFKUFk/view?usp=sharing)